# IDE Motherboard to Boot from a SATA 1T Hdd

Tags: hard-drive, sata, pata

I want to use my SATA HDD with my very old ASUS A7V8X-X motherboard (made in 2003). I intend to buy a cheap adapter for this, something similar to this one:

> http://www.cooldrives.com/satoidecofor.html

Would there be any issues if I want to boot from this SATA drive? My impression is that these kind of adapters convert SATA signal and commands to PATA directly and such a low level conversion should be transparent to the motherboard and BIOS - in case the BIOS doesn't support SATA. My motherboard definitely doesn't support SATA.

Has anyone ever used such an adapter to support a boot drive? Any success stories?

Answer (score 2):

Yes the adapters do work, I have used other brands in the past.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar ASUS motherboard from 2002 and I used a PCI raid controller, it booted of a 1tb sata. Also they are cheap on Ebay. Finally, you should purchase a better motherboard I got a Asus p4g41-m LE for 60$ at my local computer store.

Answer (score 1):

Just reading the page you linked, in particular, the part labeled "About The Chip, I would think that it translates in into a form that can be used by older boards. Common sense also dictates that if it didn't they wold almost certainly say something about incompatibility, but it says "Compatible with Ultra ATA 133 specifications".

The surest way for you to know, it use the "FREE HELP FORM" at the bottom of the page, or call and ask them. Who would know better?